# Samsung Galaxy A5 screen has broken, want to retrieve data

Tags: samsung-galaxy-a5

My samsung galaxy A5 mobile is dropped and its screen has been broken though the hand set is ringing when some one calls my nomber but I am not able to receive it.
Now I want my all media and whatsapp data back before going to give it to service center.
I would be very thankful if anyone help me to provide solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Lot's of cell phone repair shops and computer shops do data recovery if you trust them but of course that isn't free.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is achievable if the "USB Debugging" option is enabled on the phone and you authorized the computer for this USB Debugging purpose.

I know of 1 method which doesn't require you to touch your phone only if you have USB Debugging enabled:

> adb pull /sdcard/ %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\

this shall copy every file and directory from your sdcard to your Windows Desktop

Note: For internal memory you will have to check the internal memory folder, you can check it by the *`ls`* command in `/storeage/` where you should `cd`(change directory) to folders inside and check if it is your internal memory stored files.

There's another way to get a backup of your whatsapp app and whole system backup as well(system backup, not data files like whatsapp media, pictures and songs etc.) but it can only work if you are able to touch the bottom of the screen so that you can authorize for the backup, you can do so by `adb backup` and the steps are listed here :http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351

Comment: Thanks for the response dear but unfortunately USB Debugging is not enabled in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Install ADB on your PC. You can download it here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790. The program will create a shortcut on your desktop that can then be used to open a command prompt.

Step 2: Once the command prompt is open enter the following code:

Adb shell

echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >>/system/build.prop

echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >>/system/build.prop

echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mass_storage,adb" >>/system/build.prop"

Step 3: Reboot.

Step 4: At this point, simply connect your Android device to your PC and the Android Control Screen will popup allowing you to control your device via your computer.

While this solution will work for some, it is best suited to those who love coding and who have already installed USB debugging on your phone. Is this you? If so – you’re in luck!

Comment: Last I checked on my own devices, the "mass_storage" prop trick no longer works on modern (MTP-based) devices.